# cql: how can I grant a table that doesnt exist yet?

Tags: cassandra, permissions, cql

I have a user that I want to grant with CREATE ON ALL KEYSPACES, and SELECT ON mykeyspace.table1.

the problem is that mykeyspace doesn't exist yet when granting, is there an option to make it work even if mykeyspace wasn't created yet?

or should I split the granting to 2 phases?

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't grant permission on resource which not exist.
This will give you below error

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Resource <keyspace mykeyspace> doesn't exist"
```

You can make that user super user, he can do anything even can also have access to new keyspace.

You can  create super user with below command :

```
CREATE USER test WITH PASSWORD 'test' SUPERUSER ;
```

Or If you already have that user you can alter

```
ALTER USER test SUPERUSER ;
```